# HTML POST method receiving empty arrays when submiting anything on PHP file

Tags: php, html, forms, post, methods

I'm creating a searchbar, but if I type anything on it, it just returns me to the index file. It doesn't matter if I type something or not, it just redirects me to the index file, which means there's nothing set on $_POST['search']. I don't know why this is happening, I've been using this method on other files in the same proyect and it worked well.

Form Code:

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="search.php" class="input-group mb-3" style="padding-top: 5px;">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="...">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-light" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

search.php code:

```
<?php
    include('db.php'); //mysql database connection

    if(!isset($_POST['search'])){
        header('location: index.php');
    }

    $filtervalues = $_POST['search'];

?>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: None of your inputs have `name="search"`. The name of the form doesn't go into `$_POST`.

Comment: You should also exit() after a header with location.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `name` attribute on `input` tag, not the form.

```html
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="...">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `name="search"` to your button

`<button class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-light" name="search" type="submit">Search</button>`

or you can replace the tag button by the tag input like this :

```
<input type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-light" placeholder="..."   />
```